# Matching a space between occurrences in Regex

Tags: python, regex

I need assistance with matching spaces and subsequent matches in regex.

the example is as follows:

I want to match all of the following scenarios:

```
60 ml ( 1)
60ML (2 )
60ml(2) (a)
```

the regex I have used is:

```
(60\s?(?:ml)\s?(?:\w|\(.{0,3}\)){0,5})
```

link to the example: [link to regex](https://pythex.org/?regex=(60%5Cs%3F(%3F%3Aml)%5Cs%3F(%3F%3A%5Cw%7C%5C(.%7B0%2C3%7D%5C))%7B0%2C5%7D)&test_string=60%20ml%20(%201)%0A60ML%20(2%20)%0A60ml(2)%20(a)&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

the regex matches the first 2 examples, but not the instances where there is a space between (2) and (a).

any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You can match them all with `.*`. If you want to enforce requirements you must tell us what those requirements are. We could try to reverse-engineer your regex to figure out those requirements, or rules, but we shouldn't have to. You need to edit your question and begin it by stating the requirements in complete and precise manner. For example, "the string must begin with `"60"`, followed by zero or more spaces, followed by `"ml"` (case indifferent), ...". Or at least augment your example with strings that should not match and explain why they do not.

Comment: If all the spaces are optional it would be easier to remove all the spaces before attempting to match with a regex.

Comment: I thought my examples were explicit in my requirements - also my regex explained what I am matching thus far. my apologies, I'll be more explicit the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't allow for spaces between the parenthesised groups `(2)` and `(a)` in your last example. You can add `<space>*` to it to allow it to do so. Note you cannot use `\s*` unless you are only matching a single value at a time, otherwise the fact that `\s` will match newline can cause the first match to go too far.

```
(60\s?ml\s?(?:\w|\(.{0,3}\) *){0,5})
```

Note that without anchors counting repetitions doesn't really make sense. For example, this regex will match both `60ML (2 )(a)(a)(a)(a)` and `60ML (2 )(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)`, returning `60ML (2 )(a)(a)(a)(a)` in both cases. If that is not what you want, you will need to add an anchor to the end of the regex (`$` perhaps) to prevent it matching the longer string.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BGNmjV/4)

Comment: What's the point of putting `ml` in a non-capture group? (I know the OP did.)  What's the use of `{3,5}` without an anchor? If, for example, the string were `"60ML (2 )(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)"` this would match `"60ML (2 )(a)(a)(a)(a)"`. On the other hand, we really don't know what the OP wants.

Comment: @CarySwoveland as to the first point, none whatsoever. As to the second, as you say we don't know what OP wants... I have just answered the question as it was asked...

Comment: @CarySwoveland The fact that OP has a group around the repeat does give it some meaning regardless of an anchor.

Comment: OK, then make that an assumption, though I'm skeptical that's what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @CarySwoveland see my edit - do you think that is reasonable wording? btw, I really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @Nick not sure if this can be answered within this question, but is there a possibility to also match where there is an "and" and "," in the string, for example `1) 60ML (2) and (3)` `example 2) 60ML (2) (3) and (4)` `example 3) 60ML (2), (3) and (4)`

Comment: @Nick for some weird reason it won't match 60 ML, but 60 ml matches - see https://regex101.com/r/BGNmjV/6

Comment: @qbbq you need to change `\s` to ` ` (space), one of the `\s` is matching the newline at the end of `60ML`. Note that if you're just matching one line at a time this won't be an issue. https://regex101.com/r/BGNmjV/7

Comment: thanks @Nick this works as expected - thank you for the explanation too

Comment: @Nick hopefully this is the last iteration, but I can't for the life of me match a hyphen, for example: `60 ml (3)(a)-(m)`

Comment: @qbbq I reckon this has been about worthy of a new question! https://regex101.com/r/BGNmjV/8

Comment: thanks @Nick - thats the last one :) appreciate all your help